# Required/Mandatory column on grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to display a column as required by displaying red border if data is not entered. However am facing an issue that even after the value is entered, it's still displaying the red border.

My column has a combobo field which I want to make required. `allowBlank` only works when editing a node.

I am using renderer to show red borders.

```
renderer: function (value, meta, record) {
    var name = '';
    if (record.isLeaf())
    {
        if (value==null || typeof value=='undefined' || value == '')
        {
            meta.tdStyle = 'border: 1px solid red';  // Squiggly red lines
            meta.tdAttr = "data-errorqtip='Please select Assigned To'";
            name = value;
        }
        else
        {
            //meta.tdStyle = 'border: 0px solid red';  // Squiggly red lines
            //meta.tdAttr = "data-errorqtip='Please select Assigned To'";
            Ext.Array.each(allUsers, function (rec) {
                if (rec.Id == value || (rec.Name == record.data.AssignedTo))
                {
                    name = rec.Name;
                    record.data.AssignedTo = rec.Id;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

How can I remove the red borders once the data is entered? Also just on select of the column it shows me both red and blue (default) border.

How can I achieve this?